# Refresh Taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, ajax

When saving/updating a custom post type in the Admin Panel I'm hooking into `save_post_{$post->post_type}` and adding custom taxonomy terms from a linked post using `wp_set_object_terms`.
The terms are added OK but to see them in the UI I have to refresh the page as the Update button just performs an Ajax call instead of a reload.

Is it possible to either hook into the Ajax and force a refresh of the taxonomy boxes or set Wordpress to use a normal submit/reload instead of Ajax for Save/Update?

Comment: Hi, are you using Gutenberg editor?

Comment: Hi Krzysiek, yes I am.